# Дубликат. Жёсткие требования

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, дубликаты

Товарищ [Егор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/377421/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80) задал первый простенький [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097227/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-unity3d), который 100% уже был задан и не один раз, но я слишком ленив, чтобы искать и поэтому ответил на него.

После чего товарищ [Егор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/377455/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80) (не тот-же самый [Егор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/377421/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80), а дубликат) снова задал такой-же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097343/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2), являющийся дубликатом вышеупомянутого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097227/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-unity3d), но я не могу кинуть тревогу на него, как на дубликат предыдущего, поскольку он не пометил мой ответ и никто не плюсанул, что может и не произойти из-за характера вопроса.

Может стоит добавить условие, что если вопросу в ссылке на дубликат ~ < 48 часов отроду, то требование на наличие ответа снимаются?

Comment: Такое лучше на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) предлагать. P.S. извиняюсь за последнюю вашу тревогу, случайно отклонил =/

Comment: Вооот, а если бы не был ленив - то и вопроса не было б :)

Answer (score 3):

Требование к наличию ответа в дубле [было введено в 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/260198).

> That's because the proof is in the answers. If the question looks the same, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, that is not a dupe

Проще говоря, компания считает, что если на вопрос не было ответа, то это не дубль.

Также интересный [комментарий от Тима](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux/166724#comment488365_166724):

> У новых пользователей, приходящих из поисковиков, не будет достаточной репутации для использования системы вознаграждений. Таким образом, у них есть два варианта: опубликовать ответ, чтобы апнуть в списке вопросов тот вопрос, или задать новый вопрос. Я не вижу причин, чтобы существующий без ответа вопрос мешал им. В этом случае существующий вопрос перестал быть полезным и стал активно вредить. Это не то, чего мы хотим.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понимаю. Вот [свежий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1096881/217579). Почему его пытаются закрыть как дубликат, и вроде это получается. Когда он был отмечен как дубликат, то ответа ещё не было.

Comment: @0xdb хм. Мне вот тоже интересно 

Comment: @0xdb. потому что автор один и тот же

Comment: @Grundy да, тогда ошибка объяснима