# А не подправить ли причину закрытия дубликатов?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Сейчас причина закрытия дубликатов звучит как "вопрос уже был задан ранее и имеет решение" (за точность цитаты не ручаюсь, к тому же в списке причин и в описании разный текст). Однако нередко бывает так, что некоторые участники задают один и тот же вопрос (порой даже слово в слово, просто копипаста) с промежутком в пару дней, а то и в течение одного дня, если им в первый раз не дали ответ (или даже вообще закрыли вопрос). И формально текущая формулировка в части "был получен ответ" для закрытия таких вопросов не подходит.

Может, сократить?

Comment: Для начала надо определится,  стоит ли повторные сообшения от одного участника закрывать дубликатом. Дубликаты обычно это другое проявление проблемы с общим решением. Могут иметь свои "частные" ответы и часто так и остаются видимыми на сайте. Какой смысл закрывать повторные сообщения от одного участника? Их надо просто удалять.

Comment: Нельзя закрыть вопрос как дубликат другого, если на последний не дан ответ. А формулировка, кстати, выглядит так: "На этот вопрос уже дан ответ здесь". Всё верно.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Появилось мнение, [что можно и без ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10245/%d0%94%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%96%d1%91%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment43211_10246).

Comment: @0xdb Действительно, я и не знал. Спасибо за информацию :) Тогда вопрос ТС'а актуален, нужно бы подправить формулировку.

Comment: @0xdb ок, удалять. Но для этого же надо к такому вопросу привлечь внимание того, кто может удалить. Как?

Comment: Я вешаю флаг "Требуется вмешательство ..." и пишу "Участник повторяет вопрос".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для таких вопросов используйте механизм тревог. Подобные вопросы мы закрываем и объединяем.