# Пропало отображение счетчика голосов для закрытия вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, закрытие-вопросов, голосование

Имеется [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160647/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-google-maps-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и я отдал голос за закрытие в категории дубликата. Я не могу голосовать за закрытие, но у меня такая картина видна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соответственно как я понимаю не работает отображение кол-ва голосов отданных на закрытие вопроса. Может баг какой-то? Я пробовал обновить страницу, и ничего не изменилось в итоге

Comment: вопрос, на который ссылается дубликат - удален

Comment: Потому что это не дубликат, а [повтор вороса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10259). Его надо было флаговать, а не закрывать.

Comment: @0xdb, есть вероятность, что для объединения нужно закрыть сначала

Comment: @Grundy Вероятность конечно есть, но я бы ее пренебрёг и флаганул. Зачем   еще четерёх коллег в очереди проверок работой утруждать?