# Уже не копия, но ещё не дубликат

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

**Аннотация.** Моё сообщение состоит из двух частей, которые относятся к одной и той же теме, ключевое слово которой — *дубликат*.

- Первая часть является предложением по исправлению термина в справке и не слишком обременит это моё сообщение (именно поэтому я решил объединить её с чем-нибудь более весомым по моему мнению).
- Вторая — вопросом о несоответствии статей справки о практике закрытия вопросов как дубликатов.

#### Часть 1. Предложение по исправлению термина

Более пяти лет назад задавался [похожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3723/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82), в котором предлагалось изменить "копию" на "дубликат" в заголовках закрытых вопросов, так как ранее использовалась помета `[копия]`, но, на сколько я понимаю, в настоящее время состояние `[копия]` не используется (рис. 1). Поэтому я предлагаю заменить это слово в [статье справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) (рис. 2).

> [image: Дубликат]
>
> ###### Рис. 1. Закрытые вопросы помечаются состоянием [дубликат]

> [image: Неточность]
>
> ###### Рис. 2. Слово "копия" на странице справки

#### Часть 2. Вопрос о несоответствии статей справки

Наиболее близким к моему вопросу из найденных мною оказался [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10245/%d0%94%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%96%d1%91%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), заданный более полутора лет назад. Уже тогда на несоответствие было обращено внимание, а в ответе использовались выдержки из английской Меты. Но сейчас я могу открыть [статью о вопросах-дубликатах](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:%7E:text=when%20the%20questions%20share%20the%20same%20author%2C) английской справки (рис. 3) и узнать там, что вопрос может быть закрыт, даже если у оригинала не было принятого ответа.

Однако того же нельзя обнаружить в русскоязычной [версии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) справки, так как в ней явно указано, что такое невозможно (рис. 4).

> [image: Английская версия справки]
>
> ###### Рис. 3. Английский вариант статьи справки о вопросах-дубликатах

> [image: Русскоязычная версия справки]
>
> ###### Рис. 4. Русскоязычный вариант той же страницы справки

Это довольно странное обстоятельство, так как явление закрытия вопроса как дубликата из-за наличия у его автора такого же открытого вопроса распространено повсеместно (например, [вопрос cher44](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709321/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-syntax-error-on-token-else-delete-this-token) или [вопрос nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/399662/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-javascript)). Кроме того, такое явное несоответствие поведения участников нормам, изложенным в справке, меня раздражало, но я считал его справедливым.

***Так почему же содержания справок отличаются?***

---

P.S. некоторые из использованных мною меток не подходят к этому сообщению по данному в них описанию, но некоторые метки в схожих вопросах ранее уже применялись, а использование других меток я нахожу уместным.

Comment: Содержание справок отличаются, потому что некому их приводить в соответствие. Модераторы могли бы, но для этого надо пошевелиться чуть больше обычного и пошевелить КМ (community manager), роль которого сейчас вообще [неясно кто выполняет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217).